# GUI фреймворк с использованием OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, gui, теория

Добрый день, пришла в голову идея: создать платформонезависимый GUI фреймворк для создания обычных десктопных программ на C++ (по типу GTK) с рендером на OpenGL. Т.е. отрисовывать все кнопочки/текст/кастомные компоненты средствами OpenGL. В общем, стоит ли делать данный проект и насколько данная идея приемлима?

Comment: Изобретать свой Qt ?

Comment: А почему бы и нет? К тому же, я собираюсь сделать легковесный фреймворк с минимальным кол-вом зависимостей. Собственно, главный вопрос не решён, стоит ли делать фреймворк? Может есть какие-либо серъёзные минусы данного решения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут всё зависит от того, для чего такое вобще нужно и какие у вас например навыки/скиллы для такого проекта ...

Если это только для себя, то можно хоть свой `opengl` написать, а если нет, то в одиночку в любом случае будет очень изнурительно разрабатывать такой фреймворк.

Например в разработке библиотеки [glwf](https://github.com/glfw/glfw) участвуют 86 контрибютеров, и это при том, что она просто создает окошки кроссплатформенные без `GUI`, а вы хотите ещё и с `GUI` - судите сами

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ, данный фреймворк я собираюсь делать для себя.

Comment: @АлексейКузуб пожалуйста